# userInput could not be resovled

Tags: java, user-input

In my code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaLEssonFour 
{
    static Scanner userinput= new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        String contYorN = "Y";
        int h=1;
        while (contYorN.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
        {
            System.out.println(h);
            System.out.print("Continue y or n? ");
            contYorN = userInput.nextline();
            h++;


        }
    }}
```

at line 13: `contYorN = userInput.nextline();`

I get the error:

> userInput could not be resolved

I'm using Java JDK 1.7 and Eclipse indigo.

Comment: `userinput` and `userInput` not the same!!

Answer (score 4):

You wrote 'userinput' all small first and then you wrote 'userInput' with a capital I. Java thinks these are two seperate objects and therefor can not resolve 'userInput'

Comment: Same for 'nextline()' which should be 'nextLine()'